# Pandas: print pivot_table to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data

```
id   year   val
123  2014    1
123  2015    0
123  2016    1
456  2014    0
456  2015    0
456  2016    1
789  2014    1
789  2015    0
789  2015    0
```

And I want to print pivot_table and get

```
date     2014   2015   2016
ID
123        1      0      1
456        0      0      1
789        1      0      0
```

I use `group = output.pivot_table('val', index='ID', columns='date')`
but it returns not what I want

```
filtered_dates                        2013      2014      2015
ID                                                            
0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118  0.000000  0.083333  0.000000
00038d100ed66bd4f5e3699302e1152f  0.000000  0.083333  0.000000
00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401  0.000000  0.000000  0.083333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
group = output.pivot_table(index='id', values='val', columns='year', fill_value=0)
print (group)
year  2014  2015  2016
id                    
123      1     0     1
456      0     0     1
789      1     0     0
```

EDIT:

You get these values with real data, becasue there are duplicates in `id` and `year` and then `pivot_table` aggregate data. You can specify aggragation function:

```
print (output)
    id  year  val
0  123  2014    1 #duplicates1
1  123  2014    2 #duplicates1
2  123  2015    2
3  123  2016    3
4  456  2014    3
5  456  2015    7  #duplicates2
6  456  2015    5  #duplicates2
7  456  2016    1
```

```
#if aggfunc is omit, default function is np.mean
group1 = output.pivot_table(index='id', values='val', columns='year', aggfunc=np.mean)
print (group1)
year  2014  2015  2016
id                    
123    1.5     2     3
456    3.0     6     1
```

Another aggregation functions:

```
group2 = output.pivot_table(index='id', values='val', columns='year', aggfunc=len)
print (group2)
year  2014  2015  2016
id                    
123      2     1     1
456      1     2     1

group3 = output.pivot_table(index='id', values='val', columns='year', aggfunc=sum)
print (group3)
year  2014  2015  2016
id                    
123      3     2     3
456      3    12     1

group4 = output.pivot_table(index='id', values='val', columns='year', aggfunc='first')
print (group4)
year  2014  2015  2016
id                    
123      1     2     3
456      3     7     1

output['val'] = output.val.astype(str)
group5 = output.pivot_table(index='id', values='val', columns='year', aggfunc=','.join)
print (group5)
year 2014 2015 2016
id                 
123   1,2    2    3
456     3  7,5    1
```